# In Oracle Apex can you have the Region Display Selector both show and HIDE a region?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I know that clicking on an element in a Region Display Selector reveals a region, but I also need clicking on it to hide it as well, meaning no region will be shown until one of the elements of the Region Display Selector is clicked again. Is that possible?

Comment: I would use buttons for that with dynamic actions. A region display selector doesn't support any advanced features.

Comment: @KoenLostrie hm. well that sucks